# Firestore security rule for accessing documents in a collection based on user's access to documents in another collection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Let's consider the following scenario:

There are two users: `user-1` and `user-2`

There is a `lists` collection: `/lists/{id}`

It has the following documents:

```
{ id: list-1, title: 'List 1', collaborators: { user-1: true } }
{ id: list-2, title: 'List 2', collaborators: { user-2: true } }
...
```

There is also a `tasks` collection: `/tasks/{id}`

It has the following documents:

```
{ id: task-1, title: 'Task 1', listId: { list-1: true } }
{ id: task-2, title: 'Task 2', listId: { list-1: true } }
...
```

Now, let's consider that `user-1` is trying to fetch all tasks belonging to `list-1` using the following query:

```
firestore.collection('tasks').where('listId.list-1', '==', true).get()
```

And `user-2` is also trying to do the same, even though he is not a collaborator for `list-1`:

```
firestore.collection('tasks').where('listId.list-1', '==', true).get()
```

My question is, how can I write the security rules so that only `user-1` can access the tasks belonging to `list-1` and not `user-2`? The `collaborators` field of a list item should be used to control which tasks a user has access to.

In other words, `user-1` should be able to retrieve tasks with IDs `task-1` and `task-2`, whereas `user-2` shouldn't.